# Lottery odds question

Tags: probability, combinations, factorial

In this lottery 5 balls are chosen from 1-50.

A friend offers me 5 to 1 if I can get one number correct from the 5 chosen, the order it comes up doesn't matter. Is this a good bet to take?

To get one number right I use this formula.

```
         C(50,5)
       -------------
       C(5,1) × C(50-5, 5-1)
```

which gets me

```
        2,118,760
      --------------
          744,975
```

That comes out to **2.844**

TY

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are the odds of getting one ball correct 1:2.844?

Comment: To win do you have to get exactly one correct (and four incorrect); or at least one correct?

Comment: Hows many guesses do you make? 1 or 5?

Comment: You just need to get one correct. You make one guess.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you were offered $5:1$ I take that to mean that, for a $\$1$ bet you get handed $\$5$ PLUS you get your original $\$1$ back if you guess at least one of the correct numbers and that you simply lose your $\$1$ if you fail. Thus your potential profit is $5$ and your potential loss is $1$. Is this correct?

Assuming I have the question right, then we need the probability $p$ of guessing one right.  Of course we have $$p=\frac 5{50}=\frac 1{10}$$

Thus your expected profit is $$E=5\times \frac 1{10}-1\times \frac 9{10}=-\frac 4{10}$$

As this is negative, you should avoid the bet.

Comment: Yes you understood it correctly. Could you tell me why the formula I used was wrong. Is it calculating something else?

Comment: I don't understand the formula you used.  The way I am reading the problem you just get to name a single number which is then compared to the list of five. Is this correct?  If so, then I don't understand all the binomial coefficients you use.

Comment: You get 1 pick, 50 balls, 5 balls chosen. So I think we're on the same page.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious because the bet is so massively unfair.  I mean, nobody would take this bet.  You only win one in ten times but your payout is only five to one....it's not even tempting.

Comment: I mean this is what I suspect as well. I'm just trying to figure out where I'm messing up with this. I googled around and came across a site that has a lottery calculator it can be found at http://www.easysurf.cc/lotodd.htm when I enter the inputs it comes back with the number I got above.